# How to check if TextView is empty?

Tags: ios, swift, validation, uitextview

I have used this code to check if Textview is empty or not. It works fine if I will give space, but if I will press "Enter" button it allows me to enter my Data in Database. What is wrong with this?

```
func validation()->Int
{
    var i = 1

    //1st way

    if txt_view.text.isEmpty
    {
        var alert = UIAlertView()
        alert.title = "Message"
        alert.message = "Write Career Objective"
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
        alert.show()
        i = 0
    }

    //2nd way

    if txt_view.text.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet()) == ""
    {
        var alert = UIAlertView()
        alert.title = "Message"
        alert.message = "Write Career Objective"
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
        alert.show()
        i = 0
    }

    return i
}
```

Comment: [`whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCharacterSet/whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your second attempt to include new lines:

```
if txt_view.text.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(
  NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()).isEmpty
{
    var alert = UIAlertView()
    alert.title = "Message" 
    alert.message = "Write Career Objective"
    alert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
    alert.show()
    i = 0
}
```

Also I'd always prefer `isEmpty` over comparing to empty string `== ""`.

Comment: Thanks.. This Worked!!